# How do I merge rows and create line break between texts from former rows in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

If I have table like:

```
|  1  | John |
|  2  | Mary |
|  3  | Jake |
|  4  | Josh |
|  5  | Pat  |
```

And I like to merge those rows to become one row, how do I preserve the texts from all rows and create line break between those texts like the table below:

```
|  1  | John |
|     | Mary |
|     | Jake |
|     | Josh |
|     | Pat  |
```

Comment: Copy table to a text editor, then copy text from editor, and edit the cell and then paste in cell. That should work as a quick workaround.

Comment: My first thought, but I have hundreds cells that I would like to merge, that was too much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since LO 5.2, the [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function from MS Excel has been implemented in Calc.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);1;A1:A5)
```

The delimiter here is [CHAR](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CHAR_function) with ASCII value 10, which is a line break.

Answer (score 0):

"&" sign should do the trick.

formula:

```
|  1  | John | =A1&" - [whatever text] - "&B1 |
```

result:

```
|  1  | John | 1 - [whatever text] - John |
```

[formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzDqz.png)